# Using Vue events or Vuex to pass data between components (performance)?

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vuex

I'm working on an application that needs to share information from one component and another component which uses that information to update a canvas element at 30-60fps. I'm targeting low end devices, so performance is important.

I'm currently using Vuex store/get to transfer information between the two components. While it wouldn't be as clean, I realized I could also use events to pass this information up and back down the chain.

I've had a hard time finding performance information on Vuex, so before I go re-writing a significant part of my code I figured I would ask here.

I don't know if it matters, but I am currently calling the getters from an ES6 module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your app big?

I personally avoid Vuex as long as I can. The trouble with it is that if your Store gets big, it becomes a big Object, always available for you. On every page, every subpage, every Component etc. it is loaded. Which means it takes Browser's memory.

There is a trick to use Subscribe and Unsubscribe Vuex methods to add and remove Vuex modules, and use them only when they are necessary. But still they are a "global" Object.

If you really need to use Vuex try keeping it as small as you can. Don't put everything in it.

I havn't test it but I am sure `props` and `$emits` will work quicker then `mutations` and `getters`.

Comment: My store is rather small and only stores some view transform matrices. I need to use it at some point regardless as I want the pan/zoom to be consistent after the component is destroyed and restored. I might just have it store the data when the component is destroyed, and use events to pass data everywhere else.

Comment: @zachThePerson that is perfectly fine. Remember that sometimes best performance is not best code  Somethime readability, flexibility etc. of your code is more important then those couple of ms you can gain. It is all relative.

Comment: @zachThePerson I will point you to `registerModule` in the docs. You can use it if the part of code is being used only in some places  ⏩ https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#registermodule good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It actually turned out pretty clean using events, and I could feel a performance difference (it uses mouse movement, so any delay is pretty noticeable). The viewport navigation module is really small, so I don't think I need to use register-module on this one, but I have much larger modules planned, so that will be really helpful

Comment: @zachThePerson I'm glad I could help  Cheers!